# Try/Except Still throwing RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error? - Django

Tags: python, django

What's the issue with this try/except block?
I am trying to return different pages based on the account type (I have a custom user model)

```
def home(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
    try:
        if CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id).vendoruser:
            return redirect('test')
    except CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id).vendoruser.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('test2')

   return render(request, 'main/home.html')
```

returns

`RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /`

`CustomUser has no vendoruser.`

Models:

```
    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

        def __str__(self):
            return self.email

    class ClientUser(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        client_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.client_name

    class VendorUser(models.Model):
        contact_person = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
        company_address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
        company_address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
        postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=False, blank=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.company_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you don't need to do `CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)`, just use `request.user`.

You can use `hasattr` to test whether or not request.user.vendoruser` is set.

Therefore, you view can be simplified to:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if hasattr(request.user, 'vendoruser'):
            return redirect('test')
        else:
            return redirect('test2')

    return render(request, 'main/home.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

When `vendoruser` does not exist, you can not use any of it's attributes (`vendoruser.DoesNotExist` in your case). Instead do this.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist


try:
    if CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id).vendoruser:
        return redirect('test')
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    return redirect('test2')
```

Or use `DoesNotExist` from the model this field has relation with (`YourRelatedModel.DoesNotExist`)